# In VSC, how can I activate "refactor preview" when renaming a module in Python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, automated-refactoring

I wanted to rename a module in a Python project, however I would then need to update all the imports to match. The VSC Python extension has a clearly documented feature that should do this listed here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_rename-module, however when renaming the module by clicking on it and hitting F2, no such Refactor Preview tab appears. Extract Method and Extract Variable work normally. I'm having trouble finding a relevant setting to toggle and think I may be missing something obvious. I already updated VSC to 1.66 (March 2022 update) and the Python extension to v.2022.4.0 and am feeling thoroughly baffled.

Comment: I tried and found no problem. Can you provide more picture descriptions and tips given by vscode

Comment: I updated my Python extension to the pre-release version (v2022.5.10911002), and now renaming a module will rename said module in other python files in the project without asking or showing the preview tab like the documentation shows. The re-named files appear as unsaved, recently edited tabs in the editor. I'm wondering what version you happen to be on, @MingJie?

Comment: My python version is the same as you. I've tried, but as the video in the document depicts, there's no problem. Can you show me some pictures to let me know what's wrong with your python

Answer (score 1):

Note that VSCode 1.69 (June 2022) will add a [Refactoring Preview option in Command Palette (PR 151566)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/151566), following the [issue 151140 "Allow refactorings to be previewed"](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/151140): `showPreview`.

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/54879025/172922141-af06b870-1d61-4b06-9a6c-d3d7fe00d605.gif]

If `showPreview` was set to false, there would be no preview visible.